# How do I stop this looping windows update?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-update

I seem to have a computer that wants to repeatively install "Security Update for Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 (KB969856).

It says for more information click here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=7611

Interestingly, the link goes to the International language selection page @ microsoft. After installing the update, it appears next time I restatrt to be installed again.

How can I get the install to work? Otherwise how do I remove it?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always ignore an update you don't want. Untick it from the list and it will not bother you again.  If you want to get it back, you can always "restore hidden updates" from the Windows Update left menu.

Answer (score 1):

Is it Windows Vista or Windows XP?

### On Windows Vista:

1. Go to *Windows Update* in the Control Panel.
2. Click on *View available updates*.
3. Untick the update. Go back.
4. Click on *Install Updates*.

I believe it should work.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't make it clear in the post (but it's a tag) - it's XP.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this sort of thing before in Windows 2000. In the end, I resort to the following 'reset' batch file. I've always found it to kick Windows Updates into action:

```
net stop bits 
net stop wuauserv 
del /f /q %windir%\WindowsUpdate.log
del /f /s /q %windir%\SoftwareDistribution\*.*
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\system32\atl.dll 
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\system32\jscript.dll 
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\system32\msxml3.dll 
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\system32\softpub.dll 
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\system32\wuapi.dll 
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\system32\wuaueng.dll 
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\system32\wuaueng1.dll 
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\system32\wucltui.dll 
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\system32\wups.dll 
%windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\system32\wuweb.dll 
net start bits 
net start wuauserv 
wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow
```

I shouldn't think it'll be too different for XP - if at all.

Comment: Talk about overkill!